# cascading dropdown with no relation to each other

Tags: knockout.js

I have 2 dropdown but there wont be any relation to each other. I want to hide or disable elements in second dropdown depending on selection of first dropdown.

Here is fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DJGxC/10/) where you can see when i select Type in one dropdown it shows related Cars in other dropdown. 
In fiddle you can see that data is declared as below

```
filters: ["None", "Old", "New", "Super"],
items: [{ name: "Corvette", type: "Old"},
       { name: "Charger", type: "Old"},
       { name: "Prius", type: "New"},
       { name: "Magnum", type: "New"},
       { name: "McLaren", type: "Super"},
       { name: "Saleen", type: "Super"}]
```

You will see that there is relation between this two arrays. But in my actual scenario there will be no relation with each other like below

```
// Mydata will be like
 filters: ["None", "Old", "New", "Super"],
 items: [{ name: "Corvette", type: "Old"},
       { name: "Charger"},
       { name: "Prius"},
       { name: "Magnum"},
       { name: "McLaren"},
       { name: "Saleen"}]
```

How can i acheive this in knockout?

Comment: So, items without a `type` will be considered `New` or `None`?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer great to see you RP. I didnt understood your question

Comment: @RPNiemeyer If user selects None then display all the names but if he selects other than None then only display first 4 i.e Charger, Prius,Magnum and McLaren

Comment: @RPNiemeyer please let me know if there is way out here. Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: So, if they select "None" you will show all.  If they select anything else (Old, New, Super), then display the first four?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you would just want to alter your `filteredItems` computed, so that it does a `slice` on your array like:

```
self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {
    var filter = self.filter();
    if (!filter || filter == "None") {
        return self.items();
    } else {
        return self.items.slice(0, 4);
    }
});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/3y4YP/

Comment: what does this line   return self.items.slice(0, 4); do?

Comment: slice returns part of the array from a start to end index. This computed will run each time that your filter changes.

Comment: but i dont need hard coded 4 value. It can be anything. What to do for it?

Comment: What is the logic that you would use to determine what values to show given a certain choice?

Comment: If user select None then select Corvette and Charger Else select Prius,Magnum,McLaren,Saleen which means other than what we selected earlier. But the list in else part will be more than 4. So logic if user select None then select specific Cars for ex  Corvette and Charger or else select the remaining other than  Corvette and Charger

Comment: Based on your description, this would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bx6TN/